# Summing Power BI Columns

Tags: powerbi

I have a Power BI dataset that I need to use to graph product sales by product.
I am trying to figure out how to sum two columns based on values of other columns.
Usually data sets like these have it all in the same column but this is not the case.

For example:

| Product 1 | Unit Sales 1 | Product 2 | Unit Sales 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 200 | B | 100 |
| B | 5 | A | 200 |

So the result would show that product A had 400 unit sales and product B had 105 unit sales.

Thanks for your help.
-DM

Comment: It would probably help if you used a [Mark down table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) to give like just 3 rows of data and what you're hoping to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

**PowerQuery**
I suggest you look to transform your table in PowerQuery so that you have two columns only. And additionally, you can group/sum them as well.

As an example:

```
let
    Source = #table(type table [Product 1 = text, Unit Sales 1 = Int64.Type, Product 2 = text, Unit Sales 2 = Int64.Type], {{"A", 200, "B", 100}, {"B", 5, "A", 200}}),
    Stack = Table.FromColumns( { Source[Product 1] & Source[Product 2], Source[Unit Sales 1] & Source[Unit Sales 2] }, {"Product", "Unit Sales"}),
    Group = Table.Group(Stack, {"Product"}, {{"Unit Sales", each List.Sum([Unit Sales]), type nullable Int64.Type}})
in
    Group
```

If you have additional columns in your table that you want to keep, for example a Date column:

| Date | Product 1 | Unit Sales 1 | Product 2 | Unit Sales 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | A | 200 | B | 100 |
| 2023-01-02 | B | 5 | A | 200 |

Then you will need to modify the above to include the additional column(s), and you won't need the Group/Sum step either:

```
let
    Source = #table(type table [Date = date, Product 1 = text, Unit Sales 1 = Int64.Type, Product 2 = text, Unit Sales 2 = Int64.Type], {{"01/01/2023", "A", 200, "B", 100}, {"02/01/2023", "B", 5, "A", 200}}),
    Stack = Table.FromColumns( { Source[Date] & Source[Date], Source[Product 1] & Source[Product 2], Source[Unit Sales 1] & Source[Unit Sales 2] }, {"Date", "Product", "Unit Sales"})
in
    Stack
```

---

**DAX**
If for a reason you are not able to use PowerQuery to transform your table, then you can create a Measure similar to the below. You will need a separate table that has all your Products which you will use in visuals.

Use this measure if you have **no relationship** between the two tables.

```
Product Unit Sales = 
  CALCULATE(SUM('FactSale'[Unit Sales 1]), 'FactSale'[Product 1] IN DISTINCT('Product'[Product]))
  +
  CALCULATE(SUM('FactSale'[Unit Sales 2]), 'FactSale'[Product 2] IN DISTINCT('Product'[Product]))
```

- `FactSale` is the table name for your table - rename as needed
- `Product` is the separate table that has all your products listed

If you do want to use relationships, then you will need one Active and the other [Inactive relationship](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/relationships-active-inactive#inactive-relationships). Then the measure would look like:

```
Product Unit Sales = 
  CALCULATE(SUM('FactSale'[Unit Sales 1]))
  +
  CALCULATE(
    SUM('FactSale'[Unit Sales 2]),
    USERELATIONSHIP('Product'[Product], 'FactSale'[Product 2])
  )
```

Comment: Thanks Sam! The DAX formula works really well but it returns blank values for the 2nd line. I believe this is because both product columns need to have a relationship to the manual product table I created. But there doesn't seem to be a way to route both product columns to the same table in a relationship.

Comment: The measure suggested didn't expect any relationships. Either remove the relationship or look at the second part of the updated answer above to create a second but Inactive relationship, and then using the second suggested measure.

Comment: Splendid, please help mark the answer as Accepted for the benefit of all.